# Creating an “unzip” custom module

Tags: views, theming

I am creating a website that will allow users to upload projects. Project submissions will consist of .zip file. Once the user uploads their project, I need to unzip the .zip file and find the .html file . Also, it needs to be possible to upload these projects through the web interface "Add New Content" and through Node.create by way of the services module.
note I'm using the PclZip library.
This is part of the code I use when the uploaded file but it does not extract the file

```
function custom_unzip_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state) {
    if ($node->type == 'flipper') {
    $p_zipname = base_path() .'sites/default/files'.$form_state["complete form"]["#node"]->field_file["und"][0]["filename"];
    $to_extract = base_path() . 'test/';

    $zip = new PclZip($p_zipname);
    $ar = $zip->extract(PCLZIP_OPT_PATH, $to_extract);

    }
}
```

Comment: "it does not extract the file" - so please tell us what it *does*. Dies silently? Apperas to work but files are not there? Sends Drupal watchdog message? Knowing that we will be able to tell if it's Drupal problem, or should be asked on Stack Overflow - and if it is Drupal indeed, that knowledge is needed to really help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind Drupal 7 has a built in library for working with archive files.

[Archiver Zip](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.archiver.inc/class/ArchiverZip/7)

See also [system.archiver.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.archiver.inc/7)

Perhaps you'll have more success using that.

Lastly, make sure the path to the uploaded file is correct for extraction.

Comment: Nice answer, and upvoted, but note it requires PHP 5 >= 5.2.0 and PECL zip >= 1.1.0 to work. There is a slight chance Tose Sharef's hosting does not meet one of these, probably later as PHP 5.2.5 is already on Drupal's requirements list. If so, and if PclZip is accessible, his approach makes sense. We'll see when he will address concern in comments.

Comment: i am trying to work in this but it give me warning and not give me extarct file